# How to add @mention token in subject line of Power Automate teams message

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

I have a simple Power Automate workflow to send a message to a Microsoft Teams Channel. The workflow works if I put the @mention token in the body, but user has requested it in the subject line. I get following error when trying to run with @mention token in subject line - "Neither Body nor adaptive card content contains marker for mention with Id '0'. Add [Username] to the body or an adaptive card".

Any help with a workaround not involving an adaptive card?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message

> Neither Body nor adaptive card content contains marker for mention
> with Id '0'. Add 'MOD Administrator' to the body or an
> adaptive card.

[image]

Currently, Microsoft Teams only supports @mentions in the body of the message, not in the subject line. The error message you're seeing is because the @mention token is expected to be in the body or an adaptive card.